# How to parse JSON with multiple rows/results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I don't know if this is malformed JSON string or not, but I cannot work out how to parse each result to get the data out.

This is the data.d response from my $.ajax function (it calls a WebMethod in Code Behind (C#)):

```
{"Row":[
{"ID1":"TBU9THLCZS","Project":"1","ID2":"Y5468ASV73","URL":"http://blah1.com","Wave":"w1","StartDate":"18/06/2015 5:46:41 AM","EndDate":"18/06/2015 5:47:24 AM","Status":"1","Check":"0"},
{"ID1":"TBU9THLCZS","Project":"2","ID2":"T7J6SHZCH","URL":"http://blah2.com","Wave":"w1","StartDate":"23/06/2015 4:35:22 AM","EndDate":"","Status":"","Check":""}
]}
```

With all the examples I have looked at, only one or two showed something where my 'Row' is, and the solutions were not related, such as one person had a comma after the last array.

I would be happy with some pointers if not even the straight out answer.

I have tried various combinations of response.Row, response[0], using $.each, but I just can't get it.

EDIT, this is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Mgr.aspx/ShowActivity",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "ID": "null"
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response.hasOwnProperty("d") ? response.d : response;
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#lblResErr').html('<span style="color:red;">' + thrownError);
    }
});
```

At the moment I have just been trying to get ID1 value and ID2 value into the console.

EDIT (Resolved):   Thanks to YTAM and Panagiotis !

```
success: function (response) {
    var data = response.hasOwnProperty("d") ? response.d : response;
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Now the console is showing me an array of two objects, and now I know what to do with them !!

Comment: The question is marked both C# and Ajax, although it seems you are asking how to parse Json in Javascript. What did you try? Where is the code? Just parse the entire string, In any language, you'll get back an object with a `Row` array that contains 2 objects

Comment: Apologies if marking C# as well confused the issue - I thought it might best as there might be something pertinent in the fact the ajax function was calling a function in C#.

Comment: Actually, you should remove both the `ajax` and `c#` tag, add `javascript` and *post the code you tried*. It sounds as if you only have trouble accessing the properties of the resulting object. Which is kind of strange, `response.Row[0]` is the obvious choice - you have a response object with a `Row` property that is actually an array

Comment: You guys Panagiotis and YTAM are legends, that was it !  I will update my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be getting a json string from the web method rather than an actual `JavaScript` object. Parse it into a JavaScript object by
doing

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

then you'll be able to iterate over `data.Row`

Comment: Reusing the same variable for completely different things (a string and a Javascript object) is a *bad* idea

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fair enough

Comment: And I will take that onboard too !

Answer (score 2):

First you have to parse the string with JSON.parse

var data= **JSON.parse**(rowData);

Then you will get object like given below,

```
data = {
"Row": [
{
  "ID1":"TBU9THLCZS",
  "Project":"1",
  "ID2":"Y5468ASV73",
  "URL":"http://blah1.com",
  "Wave":"w1",
  "StartDate":"18/06/2015 5:46:41 AM",
  "EndDate":"18/06/2015 5:47:24 AM",
  "Status":"1",
  "Check":"0"
},
{
  "ID1":"TBU9THLCZS",
  "Project":"2",
  "ID2":"T7J6SHZCH",
  "URL":"http://blah2.com",
  "Wave":"w1",
  "StartDate":"23/06/2015 4:35:22 AM",
  "EndDate":"",
  "Status":"",
  "Check":""
}
]}
```

Here I am giving two options either direct retrieve data from data variable or through loop.

```
data.row[0].ID1
data.row[0].Project
data.row[0].ID2
```

and so on

**OR**

use loop,

```
var result = json.row;
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var object = result[i];
   for (property in object) {
    var value = object[property];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.